# Email is not getting triggerred from Logstash - ELK stack

Tags: email, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, threshold

I want to trigger e-mail from logstash, when a event occurred more then a threshold limit. I have searched and got some suggestion to configure with Mertic, but I m not getting any e-mail. Here is my code below - what wrong I have done here..? please help.

```
// This is my filter
filter{
  if [type] == "agentapp"{
    grok { // no issue with this part
    ...}
    date{ // no issue with this part
    ...}    
  // I have added this below for threshold
  if [message] =~ "Invalid sm_usergroups" {
        metrics {
            meter => ["Invalid sm_usergroups"]
            add_tag => "metric-tag"
        }
    }       
  }
}

// This is my output
output{
  if "metric-tag" in [tags] and ["Invalid sm_usergroups".rate_15m] > 1 {
    email {
    ..//email code is also working one. checked.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: also I have a doubt like, how we can check 'metric' plugin is installed in ELK, i am working on a already build stack, need to upgrade it... but im stacked for long time... any help is acceptable.

Comment: Issue was with Mertic plugin.. which wont work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with metric plugin, which wont work properly. We have done it manually, bt counting the threshold and finally sending the mail.